# Como fazer um programa calcular a área de diversos objetos separadamente utilizando os valores dados pelo usuário (scanner)

Tags: java

Sou novo aqui e novo na programação, acredito que a melhor forma de firmar os conceitos e aprender é na prática.

Por isso tentei fazer alguns programinhas básicos no `Eclipse` (também uso `Intellij`) e a princípio deu certo, quis usar o `Scanner` do `java` para poder inserir valores mas no último programa que fui fazer não consegui fazer certo e estou nisso a horas...

Acredito que seja bem simples, o programa consiste em **calcular** a **área de objetos** (triângulo e trapézio eu inseri, apenas para testar) com o valor dado pelo usuário por exemplo:

> A fórmula da área de um triângulo é `A = (b*h)/2` sendo `b = base` e `h = altura`.
>
> Os valores de `b` e `h` quem vai dar é o usuário no console e assim o programa vai calcular e retornar o valor da área `(A)` de *acordo* com o objeto geométrico escolhido.

Mas o problema não está na resolução da conta, nesta parte está tudo certinho.

O problema está na hora de fazer o usuário escolher qual objeto geométrico (triângulo ou trapézio) ele quer saber a área para o programa calcular e executar somente o bloco de código daquele objeto, ignorando o outro já que ele não foi escolhido.

O meu programa pede o valor dos dois e independente do que eu faça ele não executa só um deles, pode ser variados erros que cometi e como leigo nesse assunto peço ajuda para resolver, seja por um código totalmente novo ou reaproveitando o meu.

Segue abaixo o código:

package course;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UtilizandoScanner1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*Descubra a área do que o usuário passar
     * Trapézio: A = ((B + b)/2) * h
     * B = Base maior, b = base menor, h = altura
     * 
     * Triângulo: A = (B*h)/2
     * B = Base, h = altura
     */


    System.out.println("Bem-vindo ao calculador de área!");
    System.out.println("Informe qual objeto quer calcular: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean trapézio = true, triângulo = true;

    if(trapézio){
        Double B,b,h,A;
        //coletando os valores do usuário
        System.out.println("Informe o valor de B = base maior: ");
        B = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Informe o valor de b = base menor: ");
        b = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Informe o valor de h = altura");
        h = input.nextDouble();
        //calculando
        A = ((B + b)/2)*h;
        System.out.println("O valor dado é B: "+B+" b: "+b+" h: "+h);
        System.out.println("A área do trapézio é: "+A);
        input.close();
    }
    if(triângulo){
        Double B,h,A;
        //coletando valores do usuário
        System.out.println("Informe o valor de B = base: ");
        B = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Informe o valor de h = altura: ");
        h = input.nextDouble();
        //calculando
        A = (B*h)/2;
        System.out.println("O valor dado é B: "+B+" h: "+h);
        System.out.println("A área do triângulo é: "+A);
        input.close();
    }   


}
```

}

Comment: Você pode fazer uma espécie de menu de opções para o usuário, pedindo que ele digite 1- para triângulo, 2 para quadrado etc. Usando um `if`, vai avaliar qual a opção que ele escolheu e, então, chamar o método de acordo para aquela forma geométrica (você pode construir um para cada forma). Dentro de cada método, você pode pedir para o usuário os parâmetros que você necessita para aquela determinada forma (raio para o círculo, lado para o quadrado etc.). É uma forma bem básica de se fazer, há melhores, mas para começar está bem ok.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações, consegue dar uma olhada ?

Comment: Você definiu booleanos, mas falta pensar como você vai associar o que o usuário digitou e esses booleanos para executar o bloco de código que lhe interessa. Pense primeiro, "execute" o passo a passo do seu programa na cabeça e só então codifique. Programar é passar 90% pensando na solução do problema e 10% atualmente digitando.

Comment: Sim, compreendo que o exercício mental é essencial, mas estou nele a umas 5 horas kkkk, sério, já refiz muita coisa, fiz de novo, tentei fazer um orientado a classes e um main principal (não sei se seria assim que define) mas tá complicado.

Comment: Esqueça orientação a objetos por enquanto. Você tem questões mais básicas que isso para resolver (algo normal para um iniciante) antes. Por exemplo, explicar a si mesmo por que faz determinada coisa. Você declarou booleanos, mas não sabe o que quer fazer com eles. Que tal inicializá-los com `false` e só atribuir `true` para o booleano que representa a forma geométrica que o usuário escolheu? Claro que para isso você precisa primeiro avaliar o que o usuário escreveu para então saber qual booleano modificar, correto?

Comment: Bom, declarei booleanos para que quando o usuário digitar no console um objeto geométrico ele passe a ser verdadeiro e seja executado o bloco de código dele, e o restante dos objetos geométricos sejam falsos, não executando nenhum, mas não tô conseguindo passar isso na prática, sinto que falta alguma coisa, no código agora eu coloquei os ''if'' = true, quando coloquei falso nos dois o console não deixou eu digitar nada, sendo assim conclui que preciso arrumar um jeito dele considerar false todos menos o que foi digitado no console

Comment: Não deixa você digitar porque você na prática não oferece nenhuma chance para o usuário digitar algo fora do `if`, apenas quando o código cai em algum dos blocos dentro dele. Logo, se as variáveis são inicializadas com `false`, nenhum bloco será executado e você não terá mesmo como digitar nada. Conclui-se então que você deve oferecer uma chance a ele antes de tudo. Após ele digitar, você vai ter que pegar o que ele digitou e comparar: se ele digitou X, então devo setar o booleano X para true, se ele digitou Y, então Y deve ser true etc.

Comment: Você também concluiu que, se deixar as variáveis como `true`, seu código sempre executará todos os blocos, certo? É por isso que elas devem iniciar como `false` e só uma ser `true` por vez.

Comment: Mas independente do que eu faça ele sempre começa a executar o código pelo primeiro '' if '' e se eu por exemplo deixo trapézio como falso e triângulo como verdadeiro ele trava no trapézio e não consigo fazer ele ''pular'' esta etapa, falta algo que não adicionei no código para quando aparecer no console " Informe qual objeto quer calcular: "e eu digitar ''triângulo'' ele automaticamente pule o trapézio, ou me falta conhecimento ou estou fazendo algo errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*Descubra a área do que o usuário passar
         * Trapézio: A = ((B + b)/2) * h
         * B = Base maior, b = base menor, h = altura
         *
         * Triângulo: A = (B*h)/2
         * B = Base, h = altura
         */

        boolean trapezio = false, triangulo = false;

        System.out.println("Bem-vindo ao calculador de área!");
        System.out.println("Informe qual objeto quer calcular: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String escolhaDoUsuario = new String();
        escolhaDoUsuario = input.next();

        if(escolhaDoUsuario.equals("trapezio")) {
            trapezio = true;
        } else if(escolhaDoUsuario.equals("triangulo")) {
            triangulo = true;
        }

        if(trapezio){
            Double B,b,h,A;
            //coletando os valores do usuário
            System.out.println("Informe o valor de B = base maior: ");
            B = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Informe o valor de b = base menor: ");
            b = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Informe o valor de h = altura");
            h = input.nextDouble();
            //calculando
            A = ((B + b)/2)*h;
            System.out.println("O valor dado é B: "+B+" b: "+b+" h: "+h);
            System.out.println("A área do trapézio é: "+A);
            input.close();
        }
        if(triangulo){
            Double B,h,A;
            //coletando valores do usuário
            System.out.println("Informe o valor de B = base: ");
            B = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Informe o valor de h = altura: ");
            h = input.nextDouble();
            //calculando
            A = (B*h)/2;
            System.out.println("O valor dado é B: "+B+" h: "+h);
            System.out.println("A área do triângulo é: "+A);
            input.close();
        }
    }
```

Esta é uma implementação bem ingênua, mas a ideia era apenas finalizá-la usando a lógica que você desenvolveu. Uma "versão 2.0" poderia ter várias melhorias:

- E se o usuário digitar "TRIANGULO"?
- Usar métodos em vez de blocos de código.
- E se o usuário digitar uma forma geométrica não prevista pelo programa? E se ele não digitar nada?
- Perguntar ao usuário se ele deseja calcular outra figura em vez de o programa simplesmente sair após executar uma vez.
- Usar apenas uma estrutura de `if`.
- Eliminar os booleanos.

A lista poderia ser ainda maior. Fica por você estudar estruturas de repetição como `while`, estruturas de fluxo como o `switch`, investigar o método `equals()` que utilizei etc.

Comment: Sei que aqui está escrito para evitar um "obrigado", mas obrigado, hoje foi o primeiro dia que usei o stackoverflow e não achei que seria respondido dentro do que eu pedi, enfim, irei fazer sim um "2.0" e adicionar informações, valeu!.